# How can we find the number of solutions of the polynomial $f(x)= x^3 - 3x +b$ that lie in the interval $[-1,1]$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, polynomials, continuity, absolute-continuity

> How many solutions of the polynomial $f(x)= x^3 - 3x +b$ lie in the interval $[-1,1]$?
>
> a) None
>
> b) At most one
>
> c) One
>
> d) At least one

Comment: $b$ is undetermined?By solutions, you mean "roots"?

Comment: (e) Please add your efforts on addressing the problem statement, and show you work in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Without doing math, we can play everyone's favorite game, "Beat the Multiple Choice Test."

If $b=0$, then $x=0$ is a root. This eliminates a).  If $b=$ a billion then, by imagining the graph, we see that there are no roots in the interval, so c) and d) are eliminated.  That leaves b).

Comment: +1 If you count "thinking logically about a mathematics problem" as "doing math" then this is doing math.

Comment: Oh, please, this is hardly mathematics.

Comment: @amWhy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cVpkzZpDBA

Comment: youtube.com isn't my "go to" source for defining what the boundaries of math.  Nice try

Comment: @amWhy Math doesn't have boundaries.  I think we've discovered your problem.

Comment: Of course, it is an open set; but you never seriously answered the question.  How to beat  a multiple choice question (i.e., hacking it apart) isn't equivalent to showing an understanding of the concept/principle,theorem, technique, etc, when it's a question about such in mathematics.  Of course you're going to defend you response.  I won't argue with you anymore, in reference to the response.

Comment: @amWhy Cop out.  The old, "of course you'll respond to my nonsense" ploy.  In order to solve the problem my way, OP has to visualize the graph and try different values for $b$.  I show him that he can learn a lot about the function using the simplest things.   It didn't have to be enough, but it was for this problem.  Next time, it won't be enough, but it will get him started.  Student is improved; education happened.  Your parochial approach is exactly what Chapin is singing against.

Comment: *pats B.Goddard on the head*

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$. This has roots at $x=-1$ and $x=1$, and $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[-1,1]$, so it can have at most one root in this interval (if it had $2$ or more, we would have more critical points on the interior of this interval). This eliminates answer choice (d).

We cannot say if it necessarily has a zero in this interval, however, as $f(-1)=2+b$ and $f(1)=-2+b$ are both positive (*resp*. negative) for $b>2$ (*resp*. $b<2$). This eliminates answer choices (a) and (c), leaving us with **(b) At most one** as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$f'(x)=3x^2-3$$
$$f''(x)=6x$$ and solve the equation $$f'(x)=0$$

Comment: This will provide a bound, but you'll also need to consider some values of $b$.